# C program crashes on windows when run from Python program

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, windows, mingw

I'm trying to run a C program from a Python program using `subprocess.run()` on Windows 11. However when the C program is run using `subprocess.run()` the C program does not run and returns `3221225781`. But when I run the C program directly and not from python it runs fine and prints "Hello World!". Looking online `3221225781` means `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`. I've tried compiling the C program statically so it doesn't require any DLLs using `gcc -static -static-libgcc -o test.exe test.c` but I still get the same `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND` error. The C program is being compiled using gcc installed from mingw.

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   printf("Hello World!");
   return 0;
}
```

test.py

```
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prog = "./test.exe"
    result = subprocess.run(prog)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Are you sure `test.exe` is in **the current directory**?  Remember that the current directory is **not** necessarily the same directory where the python script is located.

Comment: Yeah, the exe and the python program are in the same directory. I also double checked and put a bogus exe path and the python program will complain it cant find the file if the exe path is wrong.

Comment: Try adding this to make it display the actual current directory `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: It prints out the path to my desktop, which is where the exe and python program are.

Comment: Your problem might be that Unix pathnames aren't windows pathnames. Remove the `./` and try again

Comment: I see that the page https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html reports how *"Resolving the path of executable (or the first item of args) is platform dependent"*, then it's not `subprocess.run` duty translating slashes to backslashes. Holds true what noted @MarcusMüller

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It works fine here (Windows 10, Python 3.11.3). The only difference is that I built test.exe with Visual Studio. What happens if you replace `"./test.exe"` with "Notepad.exe"? Here it launches unsurprisingly Notepad.

Comment: What happens if you start test.exe directly from the explorer?

Comment: @ssbssa he wrote _"...it runs fine and prints "Hello World!"_.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't know what he means with *directly*. Probably not the explorer, since the program console would immediately close again if it works.

Comment: @ssbssa most likely by typing `test` in a cmd prompt...